# Doctorate with no affiliation submitting to a publication with an undergrad co-author

Tags: publications, affiliation

I am working on a paper to submit for publication. I hold a doctorate degree but I do not teach at a college or university and the paper has nothing to do with my current employer or job function.

My co-author has a bachelor's degree, is not in school, and is not my student however the paper is based on work she is doing for her job. Her company has approved the paper for publication as it contains no property information.

My question is how would I list the affiliation? Would I leave mine blank and her's as her company? also for bachelor's degree do you list the degree? (I have never seen that)

Would this be correct:

Philip D. Noah, D.Sc.

Jane Smith

XYZ Company

Comment: It helps to remember that one of the objective of the affiliations is to help people identify and reach you later on. Although the advent of internet has nearly made the latter obsolete, it is still helpful for identifying specially if the author has a commonly occurring name. You may as well give your home address if that is ok with you. At the least, you should at least ask your employer because they might still care even if they have no contribution to the paper as you claim.

Comment: Thanks, I notice more and more that journals want an e-mail address that they can publish. I have a .gmail account I use just for that type of contact. It is difficult, I know when I do not see an affiliation it makes me wonder about the authors credentials.

Comment: Also adding an affiliation also helps the reputation of the affiliations ever so slightly. Adding your personal address instead will not advance this cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your affiliation could be "Independent Researcher" or similar, though blank might be allowed.

The other person may require permission from the company to name them, even though permission to publish has been given. It is best to check.

But your listing seems to imply that you both are affiliated with XYZ, which is not the case. You probably need to clarify that.

And yes, her degree can, and probably should, be listed. Use whatever the diploma shows: BS, BSc, ...

Comment: Listing the degree is totally dependent on the journal, I've only seen one journal ask for it (it makes author lists hella ugly) ... so maybe field-dependent if you say "should"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, of course, what you put in the initial submission and what is finally published are rarely identical, and the journal can apply its own standards. But the OP has listed his degree, I note.